# How to merge lists of tuples element-wise?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists of tuples:

```
x = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
y = [(7,),(8,),(9)]
```

And the desired output is

```
[(1,2,7),(3,4,8),(5,6,9)]
```

How should I proceed? I tried `list(zip(x,y))` but it gives `[((1,2),(7,)), ...`, which is not what I want.

Comment: for each element in the zip concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip them then concatenate them with a list comprehension:

```py
[a + b for (a, b) in zip(x, y)]
```